# How to generate Pivot table in ExcelSheet Programatically

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-pivot

I am required to generate a Pivot table in MS Excel(not in Open Office) dynamically as per the User's query.
I am programing in java and MySql(DB),so cant use the windows or MS object directly that's why wana to use VbScript . This vbscript will contain data as well as orentation on the columns in Pivot fieldList .But can any body tell me what script i should be using as i m very new to VB and objects of Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out what you need to do is to run Excel, switch on macro recording (under `Tools > Macro > Record New Macro` in Excel 2003 - the position may vary in other editions), then carry out the actions you want to automate (then stop recording).

If you then edit the macro you recorded (`Tools > Macro > Macros`), you should see the code which automates the actions you performed. This can be run as a VBScript with very little editing.

For an introduction to the basics of manipulating the Excel object model in VBScript [this link](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/excel/) looks as good as any.